# is there a blob data type for a list property?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blob, listproperty

Does anyone know if there is a blob data type I can use for GAE's datastore list property?
I want to create the following entry that contains a list of blobs in the datastore, but I get errors.

```
class DataRecord(db.Model)
     data = db.ListProperty(blob)
```

Comment: Have you tried `db.ListProperty(db.Blob)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list property of `db.Key` or `db.Blob` instead

```
data = db.ListProperty(db.Blob)
```